# C# Wpf Visual Studio Meaninglessly Insists My Class Does Not Exist In Namespace

Tags: c#, wpf, namespaces

I have class named WidthConverter under the namespace of Converter. Like this:

```
namespace Converter
{
    public class WidthConverter : IValueConverter
    {
      ...
    }
}
```

In xaml, i try to use it like this:

```
xmlns:cnv="clr-namespace:Converter"
```

In window resources:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <cnv:WidthConverter x:Key="widthConverter" />
    ....
```

It says that WidthConverter does not exist in namepace clr-namespace:Converter.
But when i press ctrl+space after cnv: it lets me select WidthConverter.

REALLLYYYYYYYYY??? This Microsoft and wpf drives me crazy..

Why does it give this error?

I don't know if anything related with this but my assembly the class in namespace.

Comment: Try a clean solution + close solution + open solution + rebuild solution + re-open window item

Comment: You probably just haven't built the project after adding that class. If it's not built, there won't be any code for the designer to load and run.

Comment: @codemonkey I tried cleaning, rebuilding the solution like thousand times and it doesn't change anything.

Comment: @Chris i already build the project after adding WidthConverter class.

Comment: I tried your code in a fresh WPF project and it's building and running just fine. Also, a space in the assembly name doesn't matter.

Comment: Which VS Version and what is the bitness of your project? The Designer has known limitations when working with x64 projects.

Comment: Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 Version 12.0.311.01.00 Update 4. I'm working on X64 project.

Comment: I suggest you post an entire project to reproduce the problem.

Comment: How are you actually using it?  This is the proper syntax:    {StaticResource widthConverter}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this problem were occurred with me when the platform of the project is x64 
try to change your platform to x86 and it rebuild your project and it will be work.
probably this occurred due to the big classes count.